# How to change model relationship value conditionally

Tags: laravel

I'm developing an application where there are different types of Order models (each Order type have his relative model).
I need to change the name of the order state attribute based on the type of order without saving it on the DB (just for being more clear to the end user).
The state attribute is a many-to-one relationship (A state can have different orders) and the OrderState model have an id and a name.

---

The Structure is the following

```
Order
 - title
 - (Some other meta data)
 - state_id

OrderState
 - id
 - name
```

The belongsTo relationship on the order use Order.state_id and Order.id

---

What I'm trying to do is when I get the order->state->name I want it to check some conditions (in this case the id of the state) and, if the order is of a specific type, return a different name instead of the default one.

The state gets declared as following in every order model:

```
public function state() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderState', 'state_id', 'id');

}
```

This is the logic i want to apply when i call order->state

On the InstantOrder model:

```
...

public function getStateAttribute() {

    if($this->state->id === 1) {
        $this->state->name = 'Foo';
    }

    return $this->state->name;
}

...
```

On the ClassicOrderModel:

```
...

public function getStateAttribute() {

    if($this->state->id === 1) {
        $this->state->name = 'Bar';
    }

    return $this->state;
}

...
```

But this don't seem to work since I get this error

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: App\ClassicOrder::$state

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/app/ClassicOrder.php:338
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:446
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:346
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:319
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1519
```

---

I was thinking about placing this logic on an observer that, when the retrieved event is fired, he apply those previously explained changes; but this don't feel right to me.

Another way of doing it I was thinking about is placing this logic on the model. This way still don't feel right and I don't see a way of doing it.

The last way I was thinking about was placing this logic on the OrderState model but I don't know how I can get the Order type.

At this point I think there is some flaw in my architecture that I don't get and that's why I'm asking for help.

If you've got until here, thanks a lot!

Wish you all a great day.

Riccardo

Comment: Without a detailed explanation on what your data structure is like and why e.g. you can't use a relationship we can't really know why you've found yourself in this position and what the best idea would be.

Comment: @apokryfos Hi, thanks for the response! I've added the data structure of the order and the order state. By the way actually I'm using a belongsTo relationship on the order model. Let me know if you need anything more

Comment: can you show an example / try to do the logic you want to have done in regards to the name check with some example of a condition, your question in general is very hard to understand.

Comment: @MartinHenriksen Hi, i've just added a snippet where I show what I want to do if I apply the logic on each respective model. Let me know if it's more understandable

Comment: That logic seems fine what does not work?

Comment: @MartinHenriksen No, I can't access state property in the state accessor.

Comment: whats the error? there is serious holes in the question related to all of this, hence you have not gotten a reply to a fairly simple problem.

Comment: @MartinHenriksen Hi, I'm sorry for the bad question, hope now it's more understandable!

Comment: In what class is the state relation and how does that tie into ClassicOrderModel vs instantOrderModel? It can not find the state if the relationship is not in the class

Comment: @MartinHenriksen The state relation is in every order model (so both ClassicOrderModel and InstantOrderModel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the problem you are facing and thanks for elaborating your question.

On `Order` you have an eloquent mutator called `state` meanwhile having a relationship called `state`. When the code resolves the state, it will use the `mutator` instead of the expected relationship. Renaming the relationship will help on the problem, call it orderstate instead. Here you see where the Laravel code makes the checks [GetAttribute](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/b14e59efa3e6c7db4b079533c399a072d9ecae5b/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L338)

Code example of how you could do it.

```
public function OrderState() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderState', 'state_id', 'id');

}


public function getStateAttribute() {

    $state = $this->OrderState;

    if($this->OrderState->id === 1) {
        $state->name = 'Bar';
    }

    return $state;
}
```